# Paging next button jumping by page number * 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having a problem with my pagination. it seems to take the number of the page I am on and multiplies it by 6 when clicking the "next array" arrow function IE: "clicking on the second page then the next arrow function it jumps to page 13-18 instead of jumping to page 7-12.

[next buttons, first array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCDsZ.png)

[second array clicking arrow buttons after click on page two jumps to the wrong section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cAhQ.png)

This is the code that creates the pagination.

```html
CreatePages() {
    this.pages = [];
    console.log({'this.iteration':this.iteration,'this.iteration * 6 - 6':this.iteration * 6 - 6,'this.iteration * 6':this.iteration * 6,'this.allPages':this.allPages})

    for (var i = this.iteration * 6 - 6; i < this.iteration * 6 && i < this.allPages; i++) //populate the pages array
    {
      console.log({'this.iteration':this.iteration,'(this.iteration - 1) * 6':(this.iteration - 1) * 6})
      if (i == (this.iteration - 1) ) {
        this.pages.push({ id: i + 1, current: true });
      }
      else
        this.pages.push({ id: i + 1, current: false });
    }
console.log({pages:this.pages})
  }
```

```html
age(id: number) {

    this.pages.forEach(function (p) {

      if (p.id != id)
        p.current = false;
      else
        p.current = true;
    })
this.iteration =id;
this.postSearch(this.query,this.iteration,this.pagesize,this.categories)

  }
```

```html
  PagingPrev() {
    this.iteration--;
    if (this.iteration <= 0) {
      this.iteration = 1;
    }
    else
      this.CreatePages();

    this.Page(this.iteration)
  }

  PagingNext() {
    this.iteration++;
    if (this.iteration > Math.ceil(this.allPages / 1)) {
      this.iteration = Math.ceil(this.allPages / 6);
    }
    else{
      this.CreatePages();
    }
    console.log({"mattspages":this.iteration})
     
    this.Page(this.iteration)
    
  }
```

Comment: Then why are you multiplying by 6 there?

Comment: This was another persons code that wasn't here before. I tried removing the 6 but I get the same problem. its taking the page number as an id then multiplying it. Kinda confusing to me.